# Java remove the first node in a linkedlist

Tags: java, linked-list, syntax-error, removeall

Thrilled to write the first stackoverflow post. I am trying to code the removefirst method for my linked list. It will remove the first element of the linkedlist while return the ListNode that was previously the first ListNode in the List. There is no syntax error but the output is wrong.

```
public ListNode removeFirst() {
    ListNode result = this.myHead;
    if (this.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        this.myHead = this.myHead.myRest;
        result.myRest = null;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Thank you for helping out!

Comment: What does "wrong" means ? What is `myRest` ?

Comment: This looks like a reasonable implementation. What's actually going wrong?

Comment: Like if I have a list (a b), after i run it, it will output List$ListNode@8b8bda4 but not (b). Each list has a ListNode called myHead. public class List {

 private ListNode myHead;
 private int mySize;
 private ListNode myRest;

Comment: @FlorentBayle Like if I have a list (a b), after i run it, it will output List$ListNode@8b8bda4 but not (b). Each list has a ListNode called myHead. public class List { private ListNode myHead; private int mySize; private ListNode myRest; public List() {
  this.myHead = null;
  this.mySize = 0;
 }

Comment: @dlev Like if I have a list (a b), after i run it, it will output List$ListNode@8b8bda4 but not (b).

Comment: Implement `toString()` in your ListNode class.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch i have a toString

Comment: @Angelo Let's see it then!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch  public String toString() {
  String rtn = "( ";
  for (ListNode node = this.myHead; node != null; node = node.myRest) {
   rtn = rtn + node.myFirst + " ";
  }
  return rtn + ")";

Comment: @Angelo Edit your question to include it, and tell us which class it's in. My guess is List, not the inner `ListNode`.

Comment: @FlorentBayle No worries! Just found out where the question is. I added this line:
this.mySize = this.mySize - 1.